# Function call inside a function, does it return to parent function after completion?

Tags: c

This may be a stupid question but I'm confusing myself anyway, when we call a function and that function calls another function does the program return to the parent function to complete any other statements?

example:

```
function parent(){
    childFunction();
    println("run the jewels");
}
```

It's just a generic question but I'm prepared for a slating so have at it...

Comment: Maybe.  (Usually, yes)

Comment: C is a "procedural" language. You can think of functions as a tree which splits into branches, and each one returns to the previous.

Comment: Yes, unless childFunction() does something unusual (like calling `longjmp`) or the process is terminated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You could've verified this yourself easily.

Comment: There are library functions which do not return to the caller, for example `exit()`. There is also a family of functions `execXX()` which only return if they are unable to hand control to a new process.

Comment: That is, in fact, why returning from a function is called *returning*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking will the code above print "run the jewels" the answer is yes. A function does not stop the rest of the code from running.

Comment: Most of the times. It could call exit() or other functions like that

Answer (score 3):

It prints "run the jewels" only if childFunction() doesn't crash/exit/jump